# Why is my Postgres / ADO / VBA text field being truncated?

Tags: vba, postgresql

I just installed Postgres and am trying some simple examples.  I used ADO in the past.

My table would be

```
create table zonk (nameone varchar primary key, dataone varchar not null);
```

I have a single row in the table where the expected length of the dataone field is around 500.

My VBA test program is the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestPostgres()

    Dim objDb_con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsdatatype As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim connString As String

    Set objDb_con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rsdatatype = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    connString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=123.456.789.010;Database=cowbell;UID=charlotte;Pwd=spider;" ' original
    connString = connString & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited;"";" ' some advice
    
    objDb_con.Open connString

    sql = "select dataone from zonk where nameone = 'new.forecast';"
    rsdatatype.Open sql, objDb_con, adOpenKeyset, adLockpessimistic
    If rsdatatype.EOF = False Then
        Debug.Print rsdatatype("dataone")
        rsdatatype.Close
    End If
    
    objDb_con.Close

End Sub
```

The problem is that whatever value comes out is truncated, ADO reports data type 202 and returned length is 320.  There was another similar problem elsewhere where the advice was to have HDR=NO

```
connString = connString & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited;"";"
```

in the connection string.  (No joy)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the Connection String.

First, connection string extended properties as mentioned in the question have to do with reading Excel tables with ADO and are not relevant for Postgres.

However, additional parameters for longer text field sizes are available.

```
connString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=123.456.789.010;Database=cowbell;UID=charlotte;Pwd=spider;MaxVarcharSize=1000000;"
```

Fields in the sample table are all varchar.

More info here: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/9363